# Get current ComboBox value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Goal is to obtain current ComboBox value.

ComboBox is filled in this part of the code:

```
List<CategoryDTO> categories = new List<CategoryDTO>();
for (Int32 index = 0; index < response.Categories.Count(); index++)
{
     categories.Add(response.Categories.ElementAt(index));
}
CboCategory.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
CboCategory.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
CboCategory.ItemsSource = categories;
```

Output:

```
CboCategory.SelectedValue = c4617c70-fa21-48c3-81da-3ddb647941b0
CboCategory.SelectedItem = Interface.Me.DTO.CategoryDTO
```

`Name` is accessible in debug mode:
[image]

How to get `CboCategory.SelectedItem.Name` value?

Comment: cast SelectedItem  to CategoryDTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by ASh, you need to cast result like this:

```
((CategoryDTO)CboCategory.SelectedItem).Name
```

Comment: Of course, there is a time limitation I'm able to do it after 10 minutes.

Comment: Oh, sure thing.

Comment: Or if you do it the WPF correct way: bind the selected value to a property on the viewmodel, that property should get/set the right type so no casting is necessary.